# React Sanity Blog External Link Not Opening in New Tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'm working on standard blog project from [Sanity Blog](https://www.sanity.io/create?template=sanity-io/sanity-template-nextjs-blog-comments) and followed [This steps to add external links](https://www.sanity.io/guides/portable-text-internal-and-external-links) but my external links are still opening in same tab.

I don't know much about sanity. Could you please help me solve it?

blockContent.js
This is how defined annotations

```
        annotations: [
          {
            name: 'link',
            type: 'object',
            title: 'External link',
            fields: [
              {
                name: 'href',
                type: 'url',
                title: 'URL'
              },
              {
                title: 'Open in new tab',
                name: 'blank',
                description: 'Read https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/',
                type: 'boolean'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'internalLink',
            type: 'object',
            title: 'Internal link',
            fields: [
              {
                name: 'reference',
                type: 'reference',
                title: 'Reference',
                to: [
                  { type: 'post' }, 
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

post-body.js
displaying blog data in this js file

```
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";

const serializers = {
  marks: {
    internalLink: ({mark, children}) => { 
      const {slug = {}} = mark
      const href = `/${slug.current}`
      return <a href={href}>{children}</a>
    }
  },
  link: ({mark, children}) => { 
    const { blank, href } = mark
    return blank ?
      <a href={href} target="_blank" rel="noopener">{children}</a>
      : <a href={href}>{children}</a>

  }
}
...
export default function PostBody({ content }) {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto" className={markdownStyles.markdown}>
      <PortableText value={content} components={components}   
    serializers={serializers} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

api.js
Sanity query

```
export async function getAllPostsWithSlug() {
  const data = await client.fetch(`*[_type == "post"]{ 'slug': slug.current }`)
  return data
}
```

Comment: What package are you using to render the portable text? Please include that information in your question.

Comment: `import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";` added into the question as well

Comment: Try destructuring `value` in your custom link params instead of `mark` and access the properties like `value.blank`, `value.href`, etc. Also, I don't think `PortableText` component takes a `serializers` prop. It only takes `value` and `components` props.